# (Guice) Extending singleton class makes seperate lists

Tags: java, servlets, singleton, guice

I have a class `Controller` which is singleton because of the Guice annotation. When I extend this class with another singleton class, I get a new List while there should only be 1 because of the annotation. Here's the code of `Controller`:

```
@Singleton
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {

  @Inject protected IAccountService accountService;
  @Inject protected ITalenService talenService;
  @Inject protected List<IAppGegevensService> appGegevensServices;
  @Inject protected List<ITalenService> talenServices;
```

I know I've got two ITalenServices, but that's because of another reason.
My module contains this piece of code:

```
@Singleton @Provides
List<IAppGegevensService> provideAppGegevensServices() {
    return new ArrayList<>();
}

@Singleton @Provides
List<ITalenService> provideTalenServices() {
    return new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Here's the code of a class which extends `Controller` and sets the lists:

```
@Singleton
public class MaakNieuweAppController extends Controller {

  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    req.setAttribute("talen", talenService.getAlleTalen());
    addAppGegevensService(accountService.findAccount((String) req.getSession().getAttribute("email")));
    addTalenService(accountService.findAccount((String) req.getSession().getAttribute("email")));
    req.getRequestDispatcher("kiezenTalen.jsp").forward(req, resp);
  }

}
```

Here's the code of a class which asks for one of the values in the lists:

```
@Singleton
@MultipartConfig
public class AlgemeneGegevensController extends Controller {

  private Account account;
  private IAppGegevensService appGegevensService;

  @Override
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    account = accountService.findAccount((String) req.getSession().getAttribute("email"));
    appGegevensService = getAppGegevensService(account);
```

As soon as I add an object to the list `appGegevensServices` or `talenServices` and ask for the list in another class (Or one specific instance in that list) it is null. How can I make sure there is only 1 list?

Comment: "I get a new List while there should only be 1 because of the annotation" You misunderstand what `@Singleton` does: it simply tells guice only to create one instance of that specific class when bound. If you've got an instance of `Controller` and one of `MaakNieuweAppController`, `Controller` isn't a singleton, because there are two instances of it.

Comment: I understand that it tells guice to create one instance of the class, but then there should only be one list too right? And why isn't Controller a singleton? It should be because of the annotation, or am I wrong? ^^

Comment: Word of advise: If you use field injection (inject annotation on attributes), be very careful what you do inside your constructor. You do not have access to injected beans here! In your example you do not access them, but if you need to initialize stuff in the constructor, its best to also use constructor injection.

Comment: I changed my code a little, I don't use my constructor anymore. Any idea why this still makes different lists?

Answer (score 1):

> I get a new List while there should only be 1 because of the annotation

You misunderstand what `@Singleton` does: it simply tells guice only to create one instance of that specific class when bound.

If you created an instance of `Controller` and an instance of `MaakNieuweAppController` "by hand", you hopefully wouldn't expect them to share the list instance - and it's no different when Guice creates them. Guice simply reuses the same instance of `Controller` over and over, and the same instance of `MaakNieuweAppController` over and over.

(Note that if you've got an instance of `Controller` and one of `MaakNieuweAppController`, `Controller` isn't a singleton anyway, because there are two instances of it.)

If you want them to share a list, you need to inject the list instance, and ensure that it is bound to a singleton instance.

```
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {
  @Inject
  protected List<IAppGegevensService> appGegevensServices;

}
```

and then

```
@Provides @Singleton
List<IAppGegevensService> provideList() { ... }
```

(or however you want to provide it)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andy! I'm a student and I'm new with Guice so it is kinda hard for me to find out where to place the provideList method. Should it be in the Controller? And where should I call this method? Again, I'm new with this. :)

Comment: It should be in your module.

Comment: You specify your guide bindings via an instance of `Module`, typically a subclass of `AbstractModule`. See [this tutorial](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/GettingStarted).

Comment: Yes i get that, but why should the `provideList()` be in the module? It doesn't have any knowledge about the IAppGegevensService list. Or should I make a list of IAppGegevensService's in the module?

Comment: I added the list to the module and injected the list in the `Controller` class, but it still makes 2 seperate Lists... Any idea why?